# aws Nodejs sdk:: autoscaling.describeAutoScalingGroups

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sdk, autoscaling

I need to get the status of the autoscaling group processes (whether they're suspended or resumed). I've written the below script which returns the properties for the given ASG but the SuspendedProcesses: value is "[Object]". How do I expand the object. The ASG I'm querying has the Terminate process suspended, so I'd expect to see this in the output of the script:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var uuid = require('uuid');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'eu-west-1' });

AWS.config.apiVersions = {
  autoscaling: '2011-01-01',
};

var autoscaling = new AWS.AutoScaling();
var params = {
AutoScalingGroupNames: ["myAutoScalingGroup"]
};

function status() {
   autoscaling.describeAutoScalingGroups(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response 
});
}

status();
```

This is the response from the above script:

```
C:\Node.js\NodeJsSamples\package01>node SuspendProcess.js
{ ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: 'myRequestId' },
  AutoScalingGroups:
   [ { AutoScalingGroupName: 'myAutoScalingGroupName',
       AutoScalingGroupARN: 'arn:aws:autoscaling:eu-west-
1:myAccNumber:autoScalingGroup:myAutoScalingGroupName',
       LaunchConfigurationName: 'myLaunchConfigurationName',
       MinSize: 1,
       MaxSize: 1,
       DesiredCapacity: 1,
       DefaultCooldown: 300,
       AvailabilityZones: [Object],
       LoadBalancerNames: [Object],
       TargetGroupARNs: [],
       HealthCheckType: 'ELB',
       HealthCheckGracePeriod: 300,
       Instances: [Object],
       CreatedTime: 2017-11-02T08:08:31.364Z,
       SuspendedProcesses: [Object],
       VPCZoneIdentifier: 'subnet-########,subnet-########,subnet-########',
       EnabledMetrics: [],
       Tags: [Object],
       TerminationPolicies: [Object],
       NewInstancesProtectedFromScaleIn: false } ] }
```

How can I expand the [Object] values?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this snipped. Is native.

```
console.log('string', require('util').inspect(<variable>, 1, 10, 1));
```

in your code:

```
function status() {
   autoscaling.describeAutoScalingGroups(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log('output', require('util').inspect(data, 1, 10, 1));           // successful response 
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to JSON.stringify(data) instead of printing only data in else clause.
If you print console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) in else condition, you will get proper response.

Answer (score -1):

Use [JSON.stringify](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) -

`var obj = { "name":"John", "age":function () {return 30;}, "city":"New York"};
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));`